# JSP Hello Page Error

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am beginner in JSP and trying to do simple jsp page. ı want to set my class fields name and surname and print on the page. My class :

```
package org.mypackage.person;

/**
 *
 * @author cemalinanc
 */
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    Person()
    {
        name = null;
        surname = null;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the surname
     */
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    /**
     * @param surname the surname to set
     */
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

}
```

and my index.jsp is like :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <form name="input form" action="response.jsp">
            Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" /> 
            Surname:
            <input type="text" name="surname" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my response.jsp page is like:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="mybean" scope="session" class="org.mypackage.person.Person" />
        <jsp:setProperty name="mybean" property="name" />
        <h1>Hello,     <jsp:getProperty name="mybean" property="name" />!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I just want to set two fields in the class and print to screen both of them but i could not. Later i tried to print just name field but again could not. I take an error like:

> The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /response.jsp (line: 15, column: 8) The value for the useBean class attribute org.mypackage.person.Person is invalid.

What is the problem with this?

If you could give me an idea i would be grateful. Thank you very much for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `Person()` constructor.

Since it isn't declared with "public", it has a default scope of "package scope" instead of "public".  Per http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/syntaxref.fm14.html, "The class must not be abstract and must have a public, no-argument constructor".

I recommend to simply just remove the constructor, as it isn't doing anything, anyway.  By default, your `name` and `surname` instance variables will already be initialized to null - and a default, public, no-arg constructor will be automatically created for you as long as no other constructors are declared.

(I'd also recommend removing the Javadoc comments from your bean class.  Javadocs (or any other documentation) should be meaningful, and something like "return the name" isn't telling us anything we don't already know.)